# If statement in case a function fails

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I have two VBA functions that gather data from Excel worksheets and copy it to Outlook.

When the worksheet is empty the function crashes the program.

I tried utilizing error statements but I want an if statement that verifies if the functions PegarData1html and pegardata2html are able to run. If not, leave it blank on the htmlbody.

```vb
Sub fupautomatico()

    Dim str1 As String
    Dim BaseCell1 As Range
    Dim Basecell2 As Range
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim today As String

    today = Date + 4
    
    Worksheets("Vencidas").Activate
    str1 = UCase(InputBox("Fornecedor"))

    Set BaseCell1 = Worksheets("Vencidas").Columns("A")
    Set Basecell2 = Worksheets("A vencer").Columns("A")
    If str1 = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
    End If
    BaseCell1.AutoFilter 1, str1, xlFilterValues
    Basecell2.AutoFilter 1, str1, xlFilterValues
    
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With olEmail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

        .Display
        .HTMLBody = "<p style=""font-size:15;font-family:Calibri ""> Bom dia ! <br><br> Tudo bem?  <br><br> Pedimos a gentileza de enviarem as repostas dos itens em atraso até a data informada.<br><br> Vencidas: <br><br>" & PegarData1HTML & "<br><br> Prestes a vencer:<br><br>" & PegarData2HTML & "<br><br> OBS: Caso alguma destas RFQs tenha sido respondida nos últimos 2 dias, ainda podem aparecer como pendência, devido ao delay do sistema.<br><br> Gentileza verificar se no próximo relatório já estará correto, e, qualquer problema, por favor, nos avise.<br><br> ATENÇÃO:O envio dessa mensagem é automatico caso haja qualquer problema com o e-mail favor avisar.  </p>" & .HTMLBody
```

The functions they are pretty much the same. Here is one.

```vb
Function PegarData1HTML()

     Dim FilmColumn As Range, FilmRow As Range, r As Range, c As Range
     Dim str As String
     Planilha2.Activate
    
     Set FilmColumn = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    str = "<table>"

    For Each r In FilmColumn
        str = str & "<tr>"
        
        Set FilmRow = Range(r, r.End(xlToRight))
        
        For Each c In FilmRow
        
            str = str & "<td>" & c.Value & "</td>"

        Next c
        str = str & "</tr>"
    Next r
    str = str & "</table>"

    PegarData1HTML = str

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not checking if the excel is not empy?

```
Function PegarData1HTML()
  Dim FilmColumn As Range, FilmRow As Range, r As Range, c As Range
  Dim str As String
  Dim LastRow as Cells
  Planilha2.Activate

  ' Get the last row number
  LastRow = Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  if LastRow <= 1 then ' If not validated, exit all
    Debug.print "No data found"
    Exit Function
  End If

  ' I think is the same from what I wrote, but I don't wanna mess your code :)
  Set FilmColumn = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

  str = "<table>"
  For Each r In FilmColumn
    str = str & "<tr>"
  
    Set FilmRow = Range(r, r.End(xlToRight))
  
    For Each c In FilmRow
      str = str & "<td>" & c.Value & "</td>"
    Next c

  str = str & "</tr>"
  Next r
  str = str & "</table>"

  PegarData1HTML = str
End Function
```